# Cef Sharp not showing popup window called using window.open

Tags: javascript, c#-4.0, popupwindow, cefsharp

I've build an application using CefSharp.WinForms. All is good but when any website uses to show a popup using javascript `window.open()` it won't work.
I've implemented ILifeSpanHandler it working very fine for the links but fails when used `window.open()`. Can any one help me how to handle `window.open()`.

## EDIT-1 LifeSpanHandler Implementation

```
public class LifeSpanHandler : ILifeSpanHandler
{
    public bool DoClose(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser)
    {
        return false;
    }

    public void OnAfterCreated(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void OnBeforeClose(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public bool OnBeforePopup(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, string targetUrl, string targetFrameName, WindowOpenDisposition targetDisposition, bool userGesture, IWindowInfo windowInfo, ref bool noJavascriptAccess, out IWebBrowser newBrowser)
    {
        var chromiumWebBrowser = (ChromiumWebBrowser)browserControl;

        ChromiumWebBrowser chromiumBrowser = null;

        var windowX = windowInfo.X;
        var windowY = windowInfo.Y;
        var windowWidth = (windowInfo.Width == int.MinValue) ? 600 : windowInfo.Width;
        var windowHeight = (windowInfo.Height == int.MinValue) ? 800 : windowInfo.Height;

        chromiumWebBrowser.Invoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            var owner = chromiumWebBrowser.FindForm();
            chromiumBrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser(targetUrl)
            {
                LifeSpanHandler = this
            };
            chromiumBrowser.SetAsPopup();

            var popup = new Form
            {
                Left = windowX,
                Top = windowY,
                Width = windowWidth,
                Height = windowHeight,
                Text = targetFrameName
            };

            owner.AddOwnedForm(popup);

            //popup.Controls.Add(new Label { Text = "CefSharp Custom Popup" });
            popup.Controls.Add(chromiumBrowser);

            popup.Show();
        }));

        newBrowser = chromiumBrowser;

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you verified the problem using the `MinimalExample`? https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample What does your `LifeSpanHandler` look like? What are you returning in `OnBeforePopup`?

Comment: Not working with the given example. for `LifeSpanHandler` see edit-1

Comment: If you set `newBrowser = null` and remove the rest of the code (keep the `return false`) does it work? The other code is just an example, I haven't tested it lately. It's not required for standard `popups`.

Comment: Not working, even when any site uses `windows.open()` OnBeforePopup is not being called.

Comment: Have you tried using the `MinimalExample`? Also by default all popups should be enabled. Just try to remove your current `LifeSpanHandler`, e.g. comment out where you assigned `browser.LifeSpanHandler = new LifeSpanHandler()`.

Comment: Yes i have tried it but not working. one more thing to add here this popups are also not working in google chrome's latest version but works in other browsers.

Comment: Using http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_open does it work?

Comment: It's working fine, but when we change `window.open` with `window.showModalDialog` then it stopped working in `google chrome` and `cefSharp browser`.

Comment: it means that the problem is with `window.showModalDialog` not with `window.open`.

Comment: You'll likely have to report that on the `Chrome` issue tracker then.

Comment: Ok i'll, but what about `cefSharp's ChromiumWebBrowser`.

Comment: When it's fixed in `Chrome`, it'll eventually be fixed in `CefSharp`, probably 3-6mths in reality. Takes a while for changes to filter down.